# Does Go runtime create OS threads(M)?

Tags: multithreading, go

`numLogicalProcessors` on Intel core i7 is `8`(2 X 4 physical cores). Linux OS.  So, eight OS threads(`M`) can work in parallel. Go runtime can assign eight contexts(`P1`, `P2`....`P8` - `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(numLogicalProcessors)`) in my Go program.

### [image]

Go follows `M:N` threading model, where `N` are *OS threads* and `M` are go routines of a Go program.

OS scheduler schedules [OS threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library). Thread states are `WAITING`, `RUNNABLE` & `EXECUTING`.

Go scheduler schedules Go routines. Go-routine states are `WAITING`, `RUNNABLE` & `EXECUTING`. Goroutine is a user level thread.

---

1. Does the runtime of a Go program explicitly create those eight OS threads(`M`)? before assigning each context(`P`) to each OS thread(`M`)?
2. If OS thread(`M1`) is pre-empted(due to time-slice) by OS scheduler, How does goroutine scheduler(`P1`) manage the state of goroutine `G1` using LRQ? Does `P1` get the notification from OS that `M1` state has changed?

Comment: It is an ambiguity. Processor has a number of cores, each core does hyberthreading. The operating system sees multiple processors. OS takes processes and schedules them among available processors. Threads are like special type of processes. They share memory with another processes. Threads are not owned by operating system. Processors are.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur Yes... *OS thread* is  Linux native thread created using `pthread_create()`. Yes... `pthread_create()` uses `clone()` system call internally. My question is... Does GO runtime creates these eight linux native threads(`M`)?

Comment: goroutine scheduler = threadpool.

Comment: @DavidHaim Threadpool of userlevel threads(Goroutines)?

Comment: no. a regular os threadpool.

Comment: @DavidHaim goroutine scheduler(`P1`) gets assigned to a single OS thread(`M1`). Why would `P1` create a thread pool of eight OS threads?

Comment: because goroutine scheduler = threadpool.what are goroutines if not stackful coroutines that are managed by an underlying threadpool? you're confusing yourself with fancy terms.

Comment: This is an implementation detail and may change from version to version or be different in gc and gcc (it is not, but it may be).

Comment: @DavidHaim So, `P` is logical processor in intel core i7 they are 8, `M` is OS thread, which one is scheduler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, Go scheduler start execution threads. The number of them can be examined or changed with [runtime.GOMAXPROCS](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS).
2. No, operating system preemption is transparent to the running process. Go runtime since version 1.14 can [preempt Go routines](https://golang.org/doc/go1.14#runtime) but this is to avoid locking threads by tight loops. It is not related to operating system preemption.

Comment: 1) Did you get my second question? let me know, if it still needs clarification 2) Go runtime is nothing but C code that performs *OS thread creation* & *syscalls*. just to add to your answer. Figure on Page 2  explains [here](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~aho/cs6998/reports/12-12-11_DeshpandeSponslerWeiss_GO.pdf)

Comment: With regards to your first answer, when you say, "Go runtime create OS threads",  Do you mean each goroutine scheduler(say `P1`) creates its corresponding OS thread `M1`?

Comment: Each goroutine scheduler runs in a separate thread started by the runtime.

Comment: You mean...., Does Go runtime launches goroutine scheduler(`P1`) as OS thread(`M1`) and goroutine scheduler(`P2`) as OS thread(`M2`) and the rest all OS threads? And `P1` is nothing more than `type p struct`

Comment: Yes, I mean that. You can check it by running any Go program and then using `pidof` and `ps -T <pid>` to view those threads. Context is a concept represented somehow in Go runtime, although I don't know the details of it.

Comment: `1` is incorrect. The number of threads may or may not equal `GOMAXPROCS`. The Go scheduler is permitted to create additional threads if a thread is held on a blocking system call so that other goroutines can continue to use CPU. There is only one goroutine scheduler per Go process, not one per thread.

Comment: @Adrian **1)** when you say `1`, I guess you are referring my question one.  **2)** When you say: "There is only one goroutine scheduler per Go process" Are you saying that, it is wrongly mentioned/understood in the query that `P1`, `P2`,`P3`...`P8` are eight goroutine schedulers. Isn't `GOMAXPROCS(8)`  creating eight goroutine schedulers?

Comment: When I say `1` I'm referring to the answer. And yes - it doesn't create eight schedulers. There is one scheduler. Each thread has a goroutine queue that could be considered a scheduler, but the global scheduler is responsible for assigning goroutines to threads, spawning and killing threads, etc.

Comment: @Adrian Thank you for correction. I updated the answer.

Comment: @Adrian if there is one goroutine scheduler, then how do I interpret this mapping  `P1` <-> `M1`, `P2`<-> `M2`, `P3`<-> `M3`... `P8`<-> `M8` that I mentioned in the query?  What does `P?` indicate? https://golang.org/src/runtime/runtime2.go#L552

Comment: `P` is a logical processor, `M` is an OS thread, `G` is a goroutine.

Comment: @Adrian When you say, "Each thread has a goroutine queue that could be considered a scheduler", Are you referring to LRQ(Local Run Queue)?

Comment: @overexchange yes.